# Why does memory usage in Pandas report the same number for integers as for object dtype?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to understand the difference in memory usage between integers and string (objects) dtypes in Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df_int = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'), dtype=int)
```

As expected, this takes around 3.2 KB of memory as each column is a 64-bit integer

```
In [38]: df_int.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    100 non-null int64
B    100 non-null int64
C    100 non-null int64
D    100 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(4)
memory usage: 3.2 KB
```

However, when I try to initialize it as a string, it is telling me that it has roughly the same memory usage

```
import pandas as pd
df_str = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'), dtype=str)

In [40]: df_str.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    100 non-null object
B    100 non-null object
C    100 non-null object
D    100 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 3.2+ KB
```

When I use `sys.getsizeof`, the difference is clear. For the dataframe containing only 64-bit integers, the size is roughly 3.3 KB (including the dataframe overhead of 24 bytes)

```
In [44]: sys.getsizeof(df_int)
Out[44]: 3304
```

For the dataframe initialized with integers converted to strings, it is nearly 24 KB

```
In [42]: sys.getsizeof(df_str)
Out[42]: 23984
```

Why does memory usage in Pandas report the same number for integers as for strings (object dtype)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html), use `'deep'`  to get the actual value (otherwise it's an estimate)

```
df_str.info(memory_usage='deep')
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
#Data columns (total 4 columns):
#A    100 non-null object
#B    100 non-null object
#C    100 non-null object
#D    100 non-null object
#dtypes: object(4)
#memory usage: 23.3 KB
```

> A value of ‘deep’ is equivalent to “True with deep introspection”.
>   Memory usage is shown in human-readable units (base-2 representation).
>   Without deep introspection a memory estimation is made based in column
>   dtype and number of rows assuming values consume the same memory
>   amount for corresponding dtypes. With deep memory introspection, a
>   real memory usage calculation is performed at the cost of
>   computational resources.

Comment: Answers my question. Thank you.